# aptitude remove pkg_name* not working like apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, wildcards, aptitude

I have uninstalled (aptitude purge) the `qt-sdk` package but there is still a lot of `qt4*` and `libqt*` packages on my system.

Is there a way to remove all these packages with `aptitude remove/purge beginning_of_pkg_name*` like we can do with `apt-get`? Maybe with bash `${}` syntax?

I don't understand why we can't do that with aptitude, it really sucks if you have to remove all this packages manually, one by one.

PS: shouldn't `aptitude purge package_name` remove all dependencies it has downloaded?

Comment: About your PS: No, the man page explains "*Purge package*" as `remove it and all its associated configuration and data files.`

Comment: @sr_ My bad, I've just tried deborphan but it doesn't remove all the unused dependencies. How to do that?

Comment: Aptitude has [many search terms](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide), maybe these help you (they probably solve the `libqt*` issue, e.g. `?name(libqt*)`)

Comment: @sr_ thanks, this solves my question. Btw, there is still some isolated dependencies like cmake that weren't installed before I downloaded qt-sqk, but that's another problem!

Comment: Using aptitude manually, I sometimes press `M` on a category, marking all packages under this category as "installed automatically" (i.e. a dependency of something) – this selects packages not a dependency of anything for deletion (and most probably is not the best way to do this; note that `Ctrl+t` lets you "cancel pending actions")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `*` with `~n`. For example `# aptitude purge qt4~n libqt4~n`.

Answer (score 2):

### Safe remove of packages with no more dependent

```
apt-get autoremove
```

That will give a list of packages pull in by dependency but no longer needed (All dependent packages removed).

Reason packages not showing up in the list

1. They are still used(dependent) by other packages
2. They are installed manually, not pull in by dependency.

### Check Reverse Dependency

To check if a package is needed by others, use `apt-rdepends -r <pacakge>`

```
# apt-rdepends -r libmagic1| head
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libmagic1
  Reverse Depends: aegis (4.24.3-3)
  Reverse Depends: aegis-web (4.24.3-3)
  Reverse Depends: dares (0.6.5-6)
  Reverse Depends: dares-qt (0.6.5-6)
  Reverse Depends: dff (1.2.0+dfsg.1-1)
  Reverse Depends: ebook-speaker (2.0-2)
  Reverse Depends: file (= 5.09-2)
  Reverse Depends: file-roller (3.4.1-0ubuntu1)
  Reverse Depends: fossology-agents (1.2.0-3.1ubuntu2)
```

That will show list of packages depending on libmagic1. The reason `head` is used is because `apt-rdepends -r` will recursively calculate the reverse dependency. To see if `libmagic1` is depended by anything, we only need the top few lines.

### Check apt-get auto-install state

To check if a package is installed manually through apt-get or aptitude

```
apt-mark showauto | grep libqt4-sql-mysql
```

or

```
apt-mark showmanual | grep libqt4-sql-mysql
```

PS: Without the `grep` `apt-mark` will show the whole list of auto or manual installed packges.

Comment: This does remove some dependencies but not libqt* package, like aptitude. Maybe that's because those libraries can be used by other softwares.

Comment: @baptx Two possibilities: (1) They are used by other packages (2) They are installed manually, not pull in by dependency.

Comment: For example, qt-sdk has installed mysql-common who depends on libmysqlclient18 and libqt4-sql-mysql. These 3 packages can't be removed automatically with apt-get autoremove or aptitude, and were only needed by qt-sdk.

Comment: `mysql-common` is pull in my either `mysql-server` or `mysql-client-x.x`. `libmysqlclient18` is pull in my `mysql-client-x.x`. So if you have mysql server or mysql client installed, mysql-coomon should not be removed. And yes ` libqt4-sql-mysql` dpeneds on `libmysqlclient18`.

Comment: On the other hand, `libqt4-sql-mysql` is not a dependency of `qt-sdk`. But another sdk, the `kdesdk`. Also in-driectly depended by lot of other kde / kde related program

Comment: If you are using KDE, blindly removing QT related packages is really not recommended. `apt-get autoremove` is much safer.

Comment: I get some reverse depends that I never heard of and are not installed on my computer, is it normal? aptitude and apt-get autoremove would not remove dependencies if they can be used by other packages, even if not installed?

Comment: "if you have mysql server or mysql client installed, mysql-coomon should not be removed"
I have none of these installed, checked with aptitude show. And I'm using Xfce.

Comment: (1) apt-rdepends walk through everything in apt db entries, including packages not install. So it is normal. (2) Is kde installed in your system? (3) `libqt4-sql-mysql` can be pull in by packages using the qt library, though not every qt application may use it, but there are quite a few. (4) You can check what is installed in your computer by `dpkg -l`. Anything start with `(ii)` is currently installed. `(rc)` is removed.

Comment: No, KDE is not installed. Sorry, I meant is it normal that none of packages printed by apt-rdepends is installed? dpkg -l mysql-server and client says no package found.

Comment: As I stated in (1) in previous comment, yes, it is normal. Moreover in (3) libqt4-sql-mysql can be pulling by many different packages.

Comment: Thanks, so the dependency will not be removed automatically since it could be used by other packages (if I install them).

Comment: That is correct. I am looking for ways to check if it is manually install.

Comment: I updated the answer for checking manually installed packages.